# FillNa in pandas dataframe based on conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-indexed pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
name  date               A   B     C
abc   2008-09-22         0   Nan    Nan
      2008-10-12         1   2      Nan
      2009-02-10         2   1      3
cde   2007-10-03         3   NaN    4
      2008-09-21         NaN Nan    Nan
      2008-04-01         5   1      Nan
```

So the expected dataframe looks like this :

```
name  date               A   B       C
abc   2008-09-22         0  Nan     Nan
      2008-10-12         1   2      Nan
      2009-02-10         2   1      3
cde   2007-10-03         3   Nan    4
      2008-09-21         0   0      0
      2008-04-01         5   1      0
```

Only thing that comes to my mind is looping which is a terrible idea.

I'll reframe my question. I need to keep all the Nan values that are not proceeded by non-Nan values. And replace the rest of the Nan by 0. I want to do this on per name basis.

I was thinking something like this - 
1. Loop through the columns for each name
2. If the first value is a Nan value then proceed to the next row 
          traverse untill a non-Nan value is obtained. Replace all Nan after this non-nan 
          value with 0
   else replace all Nan by 0 for this column.

Since I am still learning how to properly access/slice/dice dataframes specially multi-indexed ones, I do not know how to put this thought into code. Even brute force method would do for now

Comment: trying to think... if you can story the 1st Nan, can replace them after doing df.fillna(value=0, axis=1). trying to construct algorith to store and replace the 1st Na in each column should not be difficult and avoids expensive looping

Comment: Why in the result is the second C value still NaN, do you mean first Nan group?

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried it on real data so some debugging might be required.  Have not checked it against your leveled index as well  algorithm should work though:

```
# store 1st Nan
dict_of_1st_nan  = {}
for c in df.columns:
    list_of_NaNs_in_col = df.c[df.c==np.NaN].index.tolist()
    if list_of_NaNs_in_col != []:
        dict_of_1st_nan[c] = list_of_NaNs_in_col[0])
    else:
        dict_of_1st_nan[c] = None

# replace all Nan with 0
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)

# replace 1st Nan stored previously back into df
for col, idx in dict_of_1st_nan.iteritems():
    df.col[idx] = np.NaN
```

code does 2x column looping... at least not looping through rows and columns